# Is it possible to integrate TryCatch into Lambda expressions?

Tags: vb.net, function, try-catch

Is it possible to integrate the Try Catch into Lambda expressions? My VB.NET code:

```
    Dim dquery = RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(dinfo, Function(d) Try d.GetDirectories() Catch ex as UnauthorizedAccessException)
```

Is this even possible or what do I wrong?

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but, as a `Try...Catch` block requires multiple lines of code, your Lambda must be multi-line, e.g.:

```vb
Dim dquery = RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(dinfo,
                                                    Sub(d)
                                                        Try
                                                            d.GetDirectories()
                                                        Catch ex as UnauthorizedAccessException
                                                            '...
                                                        End Try
                                                    End Sub)
```